# Json content type on multipart

Tags: paw-app

On a same HTTP request, I upload files and a JSON body. I do this by using a form/multipart.

It its very convenient for files, but it is ugly for the JSON. Here is a screenshot of my request panel.

[image: Paw screenshot]

Is there an easier way to add a Text JSON content type on the request, using a Text JSON tag for example ?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this question by chance?